# Blossom's Algorithm or Maximal Matching

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, matching

I am given a complete weighted graph and I need to make pairs among the vertices so that the sum of weights is maximum.
(If I have vertices $v1, v2, v3, v4$ and if I make pairs $(v1,v2)$ and $(v3,v4)$ then only the edges connecting the vertices in the pairs respectively will contribute to the sum.)

On doing some research, I found that it can be solved with Blossom's algorithm but I am having difficulty in writing the code by myself. And also, I can't find any proper implementation of this algorithm.

Comment: The approach is right. You can use the algorithm by Micali and Vazirani to get a running time of $O(\sqrt n m)$. This is the wrong website when you are asking for an implementation. But there are a couple of papers with pre-processing and benchmarking online you can try to find the code in some of them.

Comment: I think also in the boost BGL library there is a C++ implementation of maximum matching in general graphs but I am not sure if it covers weighted matching.

Comment: Asking for implementations is off-topic here.  "I am having difficulty in writing the code by myself" is not a question and is too vague to be answerable, so that's not suitable here.  Good luck with your project!